# After closing SFTP Session/Channel automatically in java application, the netstat command shows the connection still open

Tags: java, spring, sftp, jsch, spring-integration-sftp

I have a Rest Service which create a SFTP connection to remote, store it to Map and inbuilt scheduler class keeps on polling the same connection to keep it active. If the session is already closed the SFTP connection details are removed from same Map by scheduler class. But when I do netstat command in Solaries host where the service is hosted, it shows connection is still open. Can you please guide & help to identify the issue ?

Jar used : spring-integration-sftp-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar

Connection Factory class.

```
    import com.sftpservice.exception.SftpException;
import com.sftpservice.model.SftpDetails;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.DefaultSessionFactoryLocator;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.DelegatingSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import java.time.Duration;

@Configuration
public class SftpConnectionFactory {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SftpConnectionFactory.class);
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, SessionFactory> factoryMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public DelegatingSessionFactory dsf() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        DelegatingSessionFactory dsf = new DelegatingSessionFactory(sftpSessionFactoryLocator());
        return dsf;
    }

    public DefaultSessionFactoryLocator sftpSessionFactoryLocator() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        DefaultSessionFactoryLocator fl = new DefaultSessionFactoryLocator(factoryMap);
        return fl;
    }

    public void validateAndCreateConnection(SftpDetails details) {
        try {
            if (!factoryMap.containsKey(details.getKey())) {
                //synchronized block to avoid multiple request to create connection at a time.
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (!factoryMap.containsKey(details.getKey())) {
                        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
                        logger.info("Creating sftp connection for user " + details.getUserName() + " for remote destination " + details.getRemoteDestination());
                        factory.setHost(details.getHostName());
                        factory.setPort(details.getPort());
                        factory.setUser(details.getUserName());
                        if (details.getPrivateKey() != null) {
                            factory.setPrivateKey(new ByteArrayResource(details.getPrivateKey().getBytes()));
                            factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(details.getKeyPassphrase());
                        } else {
                            factory.setPassword(details.getPassword());
                        }
                        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
                        ///create the factory locator
                        factoryMap.put(details.getKey(), factory);

                    } else {
                        logger.info("Connection already exist for user " + details.getUserName() + " for remote destination " + details.getRemoteDestination());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                logger.info("Connection already exist for user " + details.getUserName() + " for remote destination " + details.getRemoteDestination());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Failed to create and store SFTP connection. : "+e.getMessage());
            throw new SftpException(e.getMessage(), "Failed to create and store SFTP connection. : "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public  Map<String, SessionFactory> getConnectionMap(){
        return factoryMap;
    }
}
```

The scheduler class.

```
import com.sftpservice.SftpConnectionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession;

@Component
public class ScheduledTask {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTask.class);
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    @Autowired
    private SftpConnectionFactory factory;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 15000)
    public void scheduledRun() {
        factory.getConnectionMap().forEach((k, v) -> {
            SftpSession session = null;
            try {
                session = (SftpSession) factory.dsf().getFactoryLocator().getSessionFactory(k).getSession();
                //Logging to keep alive SFTP session
                if(!(session.isOpen() && session.test()))
                {
                    try {
                        factory.getConnectionMap().remove(k);
                        logger.info("Removed Session Factory details from collection : "+k);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e1)
                    {
                        logger.error("Error in remove of connection from Memory :"+k);
                        logger.error(e1.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception  e)
            {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                try {
                    factory.getConnectionMap().remove(k);
                    logger.info("Removed Session Factory details from collection : "+k);
                }
                catch(Exception e1)
                {
                    logger.error("Error in remove of connection from Memory :"+k);
                    logger.error(e1.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        logger.info("Executing Scheduled Task: "+factory.getConnectionMap().size());
    }
}
```

> Logs :
> 27.12.2021 10:30:22.019 GMT [scheduling-1] -  ERROR c.d.s.scheduller.ScheduledTask - Error in Scheduler
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
> at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:391)
> at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:60)
> at com.sftpservice.scheduller.ScheduledTask.lambda$scheduledRun$0(ScheduledTask.java:26)
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1597)
> at com.sftpservice.scheduller.ScheduledTask.scheduledRun(ScheduledTask.java:23)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
> at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
> at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
> at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:296)
> at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:385)
> ... 16 common frames omitted Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: channel is not opened.
> at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.sendChannelOpen(Channel.java:768)
> at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:151)
> at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:291)
> ... 17 common frames omitted

Comment: Is there a `close` method you should call?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I tried to closed the session by  session.close(); method in ScheduledTask scheduler, but the session object I get as null.